# Highlighting whole street with some maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, bing-maps

Is there any way to highlight/display on Google/Bing/(any other map provider) Maps **whole street** (from the beginning of the street to the end of)?

I know the existence of **Polyline** in Google Maps API, but it's just connecting two latitude points, and there is no way of making it automatic so I could display any street in some city.

Also I was thinking about **Directions**, but many street are 2 way, there is no guarante that you will mark whole street and it's just now user friendly. [Example](http://maps.google.pl/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=Zygmunta+S%C5%82omi%C5%84skiego+1,+Warszawa&daddr=Zygmunta+S%C5%82omi%C5%84skiego+19,+Warszawa&hl=en&geocode=FfFlHQMdVnFAASmLXN1PdMweRzGzleDMGE9t8A;FTdYHQMdzTRAASlhR6u5iMseRzFlMXTbVy-PJQ&sll=52.258289,21.000534&sspn=0.008603,0.022724&g=s%C5%82omi%C5%84skiego+1+warszawa&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&ll=52.25664,20.99262&spn=0.008603,0.022724&z=16)

Comment: Hey @SubZeroFX , I have a similar need. Were you able to get what you want? Share some code if you achieve it.

Comment: Likewise- Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 12):

You may want to check Mike Williams' article on how to snap points and polylines to streets with the Google Maps API:

- [Snap points (and polylines) to street](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/snap.htm)

Especially this example:

- [Click on the map and a path will be drawn that follows the streets.](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_snappath.htm)

Comment: I want to hightlight a street on Tap  see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796432/highlighting-a-street-on-google-map-in-android

Comment: Example not updated for new version of Google Maps API, but I found this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap or this: http://jsfiddle.net/HG7SV/15/

Comment: Could you update the links? They are outdated. Thx

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).  (Google and Bing won't let you access their underlying street data.)

You can show a map with OSM tiles, and use the [API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) to query for the features you're interested in displaying on the map.  [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) is a javascript mapping library that could support this.

Here's a view of Chicago showing street vectors and other features overlaid on top of the map tiles:

http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=41.902104&lon=-87.626441&zoom=18&layers=B000FTTT

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Maps you could access the vector tile road layers and use a data driven style based on the name of the road. Here is a tool that inspects the underlying data in the map tiles and highlights things that you click on. This has a lot of the basic functionality that you would need to achieve what you are asking for: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?search=inspect&sample=Inspect%20features%20under%20the%20mouse