# Highlighting a street on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible in `android` to highlight a street on `google map` as the user taps on the 
street? Currently I am working on an `app` which would identify the streets where a parking 
slot is available.

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle could help:

```
// init map
var myOptions = {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

// init directions service
var dirService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var dirRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
dirRenderer.setMap(map);

// highlight a street
var request = {
  origin: "48.1252,11.5407",
  destination: "48.13376,11.5535",
  //waypoints: [{location:"48.12449,11.5536"}, {location:"48.12515,11.5569"}],
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
dirService.route(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    dirRenderer.setDirections(result);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HG7SV/15/

Additional options:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions